# Can CSS be used to style an element based on it's order in the DOM?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I need to put a style on an element, but the element does not have a class or id, nor can I edit that portion of the code to put a class or id on it.

In jQuery, I would select it with .eq[4] or something, but I can only use CSS.

So the question is - can I style the second <td> in the second <tr>?

```
<table class="tableClass">
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>...</td>
        <td> I NEED TO STYLE THIS ONE </td>
        <td>...</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I am familiar with the CSS3 :nth-child() Selector, but it technically "Specifies a style for every element that is the nth child of its parent", but that selects the second <td> in EACH <tr>, which is not what I need...

Comment: If you use :nth-child(x) to select the second <tr> and then the second <td> within that tr, your styles won't get applied to each <tr>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an alternate method that also works in IE7 and IE8 for better compatibility:

```
.tableClass tr + tr > td + td {
  /* selects 2nd to last td from 2nd to last rows.
     Do something here with some CSS instructions of your choice.
     Beware of thead and th, they aren't expected in your example */
}
.tableClass tr + tr > td + td + td,
.tableClass tr + tr + tr > td + td {
  /* selects 3rd to last td from 2nd to last rows and also
     2nd to last td from 3rd to last rows.
     Cancel here everything you did in previous CSS rule! */
}
```

- `td + td` selects everything except the first `td` and `td + td + td` selects everything except the first and second `td`: with 2 CSS rules you're done. There's added complexity in your example because you also need to consider rows, but you just have to combine the latter selector rule with `tr + tr + tr` selector.
- This is a wonderful trick for replacing `:not(:first-child)` and it's worth knowing about it; it's up to you to use it or not when it gets more complicated like in your example.
- The `+` can be replaced by a `~` (general sibling) when you're dealing with different elements like a h3 followed by p then h4 then again p. There'd be no `p + p` here but there'd still be a `p ~ p`.
- The above code works whether there's a `tbody` element between `table` and `tr` or not, as it doesn't expect each `tr` to be a child of `table`, only a descendant.

Comment: You can just use `tr:first-child + tr` and `td:first-child + td` so you don't need to undo the styles.

Comment: Boom!  Thanks!  Backward compatibility is an issue, so an extra thank you!

Comment: You should avoid tagging your question [css3] if you're looking for backward-compatible code ;)

Answer (score 3):

You can use `:nth-child()`, but you need to use it with *both* the `td` *and* its parent `tr`:

```
.tableClass > tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sure, use the `nth-child` selector. In this case,

```
table tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(2)
```

Here's a [great explanation](http://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/) of how this works.